# Missing service file

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, crash, systemd-networkd

Server - Ubuntu Bionic 18.04, Application - HAproxy.

In one of our app servers, the networking service (the unit file was made by our provisioning team) suddenly disappeared. We received notifications that sshd service was failing, when we consoled to the server and checked what is happening, we found network service disappeared with no trace.

I checked journal log, dmesg, syslog, sar report and whatever that I am aware of, I see no trace. We can rebuild the server, that is not an issue, but not being able to figure out what happened during that time is bothering me.

In the log, I only see connectivity errors like DNS failures, not getting connected to the syslog servers and etc. but not a single clue of what the system this way. I don't even see any coredumps.

Any directions would be really helpful !

Thanks

Comment: Where *was* the file -- in what path? Does the containing directory have a recent timestamp?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, yes, the directory has a timestamp of 04:05 UTC, but we received alerts around 08:xx UTC. the files was under `/etc/system/systemd`